Maximum sum of matrix elements
Given a $n\times m$ matrix $\mathbf A$ with positive values, how can I find contiguous subset of indices (might be empty) for each row, such that those sets are disjoint and overall sum of all elements at those indices will be maximized?
For example:
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 6 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 2 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Maximum sum will be:
$$(6) + (4) + (9) = 19$$
P.S.: I don't need all solutions, any, which maximizes the sum will be good.
I implemented the following algorithm: at each iteration it calculates average of subarray in each row. Then adds a single value to any of the arrays left or right, which maximizes the sum of averages. E.g.
Iter 1 (check all possible values):
$$
  (1), (), () \to 1\\
  (6), (), () \to 6\\
  ...\\
  (), (), (9) \to 9 \mathrm{(best)}
$$
Iter 2:
$$
  (6), (), (9) \to 15\mathrm{(best)}\\
  (), (5), (9) \to 14\\
  (), (), (2,9) \to 5.5
$$
Iter 3:
$$
  (6), (4), (9) \to 19\mathrm{(best)}
$$
But I don't think this algorithm will always find optimal value.

Is you problem to find the maximum of $n$ elements where each element lies in disjoint columns and rows? That is, a selected element must not share the same column or the same row as any other element?
